# Need help implementing drag and easing in XAML/C#

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

It's an app in xaml with C#.

I am implementing Drag feature on one of our element. The [sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-3dff271b/sourcecode?fileId=44758&pathId=962809525) is useful to some extent.

I want to have an easing function on the element i.e. once the user drags the element and release it, it should ease out/exponential back to it's original position.

Here's the sample code of what I was able to get done: http://sdrv.ms/RxXVdw

What I am looking for is:

1) Review help: Is that the correct and best way to do it? Or can it be done in a better and more cleaner way?

2) Refactoring help: What would be the best way to reuse that code in two ways:

- I may be two or more elements on the page that are draggable.
- I need to use the same code with more than one page

3) One other issue is when I try to drag the the item when it's easing out.

I am trying to figure it out but in the meanwhile hoping to get help from community.

Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WinRTBehaviors](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) and [DragFlickBehavior](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/porting-dragflickbehavior-from-windows.html) is the solution I found and it works for our app pretty well.